# How can we create a code template for cakephp 3 views (.ctp file) in netbeans

Tags: templates, cakephp, netbeans

How I can create a code template for CakePHP 3 views (.ctp files) in Netbeans. I want, as example something like <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to get

```
 <?=   ?>
```

The problem is that I don't know which language I could select in the Options-tools-Editor in Netbeans. ctp is not listed as language where I can see PHP and others languages. I have already installed the CakePHP 3 framework and activated it for my current project.

Comment: I tried with HTML and it seems to work

Comment: `.ctp` contains PHP code so you should select PHP.

Comment: @Holt I tried PHP (netbeans 7.3) but it works only when already inside `<?php ?>` tags while does not work when you actually need it, that is outside php tags. I tried HTML and it works.

Comment: Thank you Arilia, it works fine in HTML.